# Styling a jQuery-ui-dialog with shadows

Tags: css, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to style a jQuery-ui-dialog with shadows. I have a sample in which the dialog/popup is styled with nested divs. A picture for each corner and a line for each side which provides the variability in heigth and width.
My first solution was to give the header an image and the content a long one, which is cut depending on how much content is in the dialog. This provides variability in height, but not in width of the element.

http://www.pictureupload.de/originals/pictures/230112103022_popup-example.jpg

This is what it should look like.
Any ideas or a better stylable dialog/popup than the one from jQuery-ui?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2kj9G/1/

Comment: Looks a lot like I want it. Any chance that the shadow appears just on the right side and on the bottom?

Comment: Ok i found out how. Thank you very much.

Comment: Chris if you found a solution then please share instead of running away with it!

Answer (score -1):

You can also use jquery ui dialog's `dialogClass` property to give a class, and give ui's shadow class `ui-widget-shadow`.

```
$("#editPanel").dialog({
   width: 400,
   modal: true, 
   dialogClass: 'ui-widget-shadow'
});
```